# Setting up Crystal Reports 9 with a Classic ASP application on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp-classic, crystal-reports, windows-server-2008-r2

I have configured a Classic ASP application on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 RS. I have setup the App Pool to run in 32bit mode. Application is working just fine. The issue is with Crystal Reports. I have installed Crystal Reports 9 on server but get the following error when try to open report:

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0115' 

Unexpected error 

/app/reports/report.asp 

A trappable error (C0000005) occurred in an external object. The script cannot continue running.
```

I did some research on it and it seems that CR 9 won't run on Windows Server 2008, and someone reported that upgrading the CR 11.5 + SP6 did the job for them.

Is there a way to make CR9 running on Windows Server 2008, or where I can find CR 11.5 runtime that works with classic ASP?